# How to get the Bluetooth major device class in Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it possible to get the major device class of the device where the app is running on?

You can get the device class for remote devices with this call:

```
bluetoothDevice.getBluetoothClass().getMajorDeviceClass()
```

Here is the link:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.Major.html

Thanks in advance!

Fabian